# Prove that REG is closed against removing all but lexicographicaly largest words (per length)

Tags: formal-languages, closure-properties

> Let $\Sigma_n = \{0, 1, ... , n-1\}$.  Suppose $L \subseteq$ $\Sigma^*_n$, and let
>
> $\qquad\displaystyle\mathcal{B}(L) = \{ x \in L : x = \textrm{lex}\max L_m, m \in \mathbb{N}_0 \}$,
>
> where $L_m = L \cap \Sigma_n^m$ and $\mathrm{lex}\max$ denoting the lexicographic maximum.
>
> For example, $\mathcal{B}(\{0,1\}^*) = 1^*$ and $\mathcal{B}(\epsilon \cup 1(0 \cup 01)^*) = (10)^*(\epsilon \cup 1)$.  Prove that if $L$ is regular, then so is $\mathcal{B}(L)$.

Any hints?  I was thinking of perfect shuffling $L$ with itself, and then defining a morphism to compare each pair of characters in a shuffle to determine which is the lexicographically greater one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the basic idea. Suppose that $x0y \in L$. When would $x0y \notin \mathcal{B}(L)$? Exactly when $x1z \in L$ for some $|z| = |y|$. When does that happen? Fix some DFA for $L$, and suppose that after reading $x1$, it is at state $q$. Parikh's theorem shows that the set of lengths $\ell$ such that $x1z \in L$ for some $|z| = \ell$ is eventually periodic, that is, it is of the form $L_0(q) \cup \{k m(q) + a : a \in L_1(q) \text{ and } k \geq 0\}$ for some finite $L_0(q),L_1(q)$. We can further assume that $m(q) = m$ is the same for all states $q$, since there are only finitely many of them and we can take the LCM of the minimal periods.

As we read more and more zeroes, we obtain more and more constraints, which can be summarized in the form: the word cannot end in $\ell$ characters for $\ell \in L_0 + \{ km + a : a \in L_1 \}$. Note that there are only finitely many possibilities for $L_0$ and $L_1$, since $\max L_0 \leq \max_q \max L_0(q)$, and similarly for $L_1$. This means that we can store and maintain this information in a finite state automaton, and use it to decide $\mathcal{B}(L)$.

Comment: Unfortunately, the course I am taking in which this problem was posed has not yet covered Parikh's Theorem.  Is there a simpler way to account for your observations without invoking this theorem?

Comment: Perhaps. But Parikh's theorem (for regular languages) isn't so hard to prove – any DFA on a single letter alphabet has the general form of a $\rho$ (a path closing onto itself), from which the theorem follows immediately. This is not complicated technology so I see no reason to limit ourselves artificially, just because this or that idea hasn't been covered in lecture. You can include the proof of Parikh's theorem as part of your answer.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with some of the notation in your answer.  What are $L_0$, $L_1$, and $m$?

Comment: It's notation I made up. These are some finite sets of integers.

Comment: In particular, what are each of these finite sets of integers?  It appears that each is related to state q in some way?  These probably have something to do with Parikh's theorem, and that's why I don't immediately understand them.

Comment: Consider the set of lengths $\ell$ such that starting at state $q$, there is a way to get to an accepting state in $\ell$ steps. Parikh's theorem shows that this set $S$ is eventually periodic, that is for some $n_0,m$ it is the case the for $n \geq n_0$, $n \in S$ iff $n + m \in S$. This implies that $S = L_0 \cup \{\ell + km : \ell \in L_1, k \geq 0\}$ for some finite $L_0,L_1$ and some $m \geq 1$.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the language $\mathrm{less}(L)$ of all strings that are of the same length as one in $L$ but lexicographically less. For a two letter alphabet these are strings of the form $x0z$ with $x1y\in L$ and $|y|=|z|$.

Now $\mathrm{less}(L)$ is regular, and can be accepted by a nondeterministic automaton. It runs as the original automaton $\mathcal A$ for $L$, but at some nondeterministic point, when $\mathcal A$ reads a $1$, then the new automaton reads a $0$.  Now the new automaton reads any letter (from $z$), and takes a step on whatever letter in $\mathcal A$ (the corresponding $y$). It accepts when this simulation accepts.

If everything goes well, then $\mathcal B(L) = L - \mathrm{less}(L)$ is regular.

Comment: This proof is much simpler than mine!

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Thanks. However, from your solution I learned that it seemed better to look at the complement. Until then I tried do do the construction directly.